# Fortran subroutine left to user

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying in an object-oriented fashion to have a type that implements all functionalities, except for one function that should be implemented by the user.

Suppose I have two modules with types, an `animal` and a `cat` extending `animal`. Now I'd like to implement a way of passing a custom procedure to **any animal**. I don't know what is the best way of implementing such a feature. Right now I've succeeded in having all `cat` objects have a function caller that that will take a subroutine as an argument, but **only if the type is explicit**, or in other words, if the type is not an `animal` and at runtime I create a `cat`:

**animal**

```
module animal_module
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: animal
        private
        integer, public :: nlegs = -1
    contains
        procedure :: legs
        procedure :: speak
    end type animal

    interface animal
        module procedure init_animal
    end interface animal

contains

    type(animal) function init_animal(this)
        class(animal), intent(inout) :: this
        print *, "Animal!"
        this%nlegs = -4
    end function init_animal

    function legs(this) result(n)
        class(animal), intent(in) :: this
        integer :: n
        n = this%nlegs
    end function legs

    subroutine speak(this, ntimes)
        class(animal), intent(in) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: ntimes
        integer :: i

        do i = 1, ntimes
            print *, "generic animal :: speak"
        end do
    end subroutine speak

end module animal_module
```

**cat**

```
module cat_module
    use animal_module, only : animal
    implicit none

    type, extends(animal) :: cat
        private
        real :: hidden = 23.
    contains
        ! something like this? maybe a pointer?
        procedure :: caller
        procedure :: speak
    end type cat

    interface cat
        module procedure init_cat
    end interface cat

    abstract interface
        subroutine sub_interface
        end subroutine
    end interface

contains

    type(cat) function init_cat()
        print *, "Cat!"
        init_cat%nlegs = 4
    end function init_cat

    subroutine caller(this, sub)
        class(cat), intent(inout) :: this
        procedure(sub_interface) :: sub

        print *, "caller begin", this%nlegs
        call sub()
        print *, "caller ended", this%nlegs
    end subroutine caller

    subroutine speak(this, ntimes)
        class(cat), intent(in) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: ntimes
        integer :: i

        do i = 1, ntimes
            print *, "cat :: meow"
        end do
    end subroutine speak

end module cat_module
```

**main program**

```
subroutine ahoy
    print *, "ahoy"
end subroutine ahoy

program oo
    use animal_module
    use cat_module
    use bee_module
    implicit none

    class(animal), allocatable :: q
    procedure(sub_interface) :: ahoy
    class(cat), allocatable :: p

    ! THIS WON'T WORK
    allocate(cat :: q)
    q = cat()
    call q%caller(ahoy)

    ! no problem with this
    allocate(cat :: p)
    p = cat()
    call p%caller(ahoy)
end program
```

The error I am getting in calling `caller` from an `animal` is

```
/oo/main.F90(28): error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure.   [CALLER]
    call q%caller(ahoy)
-----------^
```

As far as I understand, this should normal: as `animal` has no clue a `cat` contains `caller`, it will not work. Am I right?

How can I let users implement a subroutine that will be called by a `caller` function? The called function **should have access to the type**, the user-provided function should be able to modify the `hidden` integer in a `cat` object.